# need to understand how the code is working

Tags: algorithm, loops, logic

```
num = 2
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print(num, "is not a prime number")
            break
    else:
        print(num, "is a prime number")

else:
    print(num, "is not a prime number")
```

The above code works. I have an issue understanding the logic. When n=2, and the first iteration is run in the for loop, i=2,

so num=2,i=2. Therefore, num%i==0, and it should break and print '2 is not a prime number'

I am fairly new to coding. So, I appreciate all the help. Thank you.

Comment: Range(2,2) means that the for loop is never entered. So we go to the else statement which says 2 is a print number.

Comment: For what it's worth, `for-else` is a pretty niche Python feature and probably makes this code more confusing than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

When `num == 0` the for loop never enters since `range(2, 2)` just like `range(0)` is zero.

Now, your for loop has an `else` clause. This else clause hits in 2 cases: The for loop runs in full to the end without breaking somewhere in the middle or the for loop doesn't run at all, like in your case. These 2 cases are practically one case, in general. The else clause of a for loop hits when the loop runs in full, which not running at all because `range(0)` can be seen as a rewording of running successfully in full, because 0 is the full range of this for loop.

So, your code goes directly to the else clause of the for loop and the condition `num%i==0` is never checked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're assuming that value is entering in the for loop.
To clarify,
if you run

```
for i in range(n,n):
    print(i)
```

You'll no receive any response.

So, since your code has a for-else condition is this case can be understood as:

```
if num>2:
   for i = 2 to num:
      checking
else:
 print "not a prime"
```

:)
For the rest of the code is just checking that any previous number (of num) can divide num.